# Not able to connect to my RHEL 5 box via Nomachine NX suddenly

Tags: rhel-5, nx, nx-server

I have installed NXServer, Client and Node (v3.x) on my RHEL box (using root). The nxserver is in running state. And I was able to connect from my Windows box.
Now suddently, when I try to connect to my RHEL box from my Windows laptop, it says "NX server is not available or the NX access was disabled on host". Can someone guide me through fixing this?

Comment: I have tried re-generating the keys using nxserver --keygen command and have copied them onto my client. It won't connect still. I see that authorized_keys to under <home>\.ssh folder is empty, and known_hosts doesn't have an entry for my client. Is this a problem?